Crispy tag leads to Hidden Field TOTAL_FORMS is a required field. error on POST
I have the following form in my template:
   <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ formset.management_form }}

    {% crispy blog_form %}
    
    
      
      {% for form in formset %}
        {% crispy form %}
      {% endfor %}

    <button type="submit">Save</button>
  </form>

However: when I post this I get the following error:

Hidden Field TOTAL_FORMS is a required field.

and

Hidden field INITIAL_FORMS is a required field.

This form works well when I don't use the crispy tags. I want to use crispy forms to make the form look good. What am I missing and how can I fix it?
My form looks like this:
class BlogForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Blog
        fields = ['name','teaser','hero_image','text','video','category_tag','brand_tag','bottle_tag']

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.helper = FormHelper()
        self.helper.layout = Layout(
            Div(
            Row('name', css_class='form-row my-1'),
            Row('teaser', css_class='form-control, my-1'),
            Row('text', css_class='form-control, my-1'),
            Row('hero_image', css_class='form-control-file form-row my-1'),
            Row('video', css_class='form-control-file form-row my-1'),
            Row(
            Column('category_tag', css_class='form-group col-md-4 my-1'),
            Column('brand_tag', css_class='form-group col-md-4 my-1'),
            Column('bottle_tag', css_class='form-group col-md-4 my-1'),
            ),
            Submit('submit', 'Save', css_class='my-3 btn btn-secondary')

            ))
        
        
class BlogImageForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = BlogImage
        fields = ['image']

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.helper = FormHelper()
        self.form_method = 'post'
        self.helper.layout = Layout(
            Div(
            Row('image', css_class='form-row my-1'),
            ))

